# Block MsgBox From External Application Using VB.Net

Tags: windows, vb.net, block, intercept, msgbox

Is there a way to intercept a MsgBox() from an external application and block it using VB.Net?

For this discussion, let's say the MsgBox Title is "SQL Application" and the Message is "SQL Error - Try Again".

I have found some examples of looking for the MsgBox to pop-up (by watching for the Window title) and then sending key(s) to press OK, but I was curious if the whole process could be avoided. Otherwise, the user still sees a MsgBox or a "flash", even if it's only temporary.

Is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could something like detours (see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), and write a detour for messagebox that you load into your process, BUT there are several issues:

1) it's 32 bit only, unless you pay for the pro version
2) the development effort involved may be non-trivial, esp if you dont have a lot of inhouse C/C++ experience.  I suppose you could write a managed wrapper for detours, but that sounds kind of involved too.
3) You cant use it commercially without the pro version.

is this an app you've inherited?

Comment: No, it's tied to a control that I've placed on a form. It has a MsgBox that fires in certain circumstances, but I need to hide it. There is no event for the control that fires so I can't intercept it that way.

Comment: And for those wondering, no... it's not a licensing (nag screen) message that's coming up that I'm trying to block. It's all legit.

Comment: No, they can't. Thanks, but I'd prefer to stay focused on the question. I appreciate your answer. I checked out the detour. I was expecting something a little more "built-in" to .Net. If there are no other answers, I'll accept yours. It technically does what I'm asking.